# Minutes or Seconds without a leading 0 PHP

Tags: php, date

I am in the midst of changing the dates in my database to something else. However, when getting them to convert to the new style, I notice that some of them are missing a leading 0 for the minutes or seconds.

```
$origDate = Sat Jan 19 16:15:3 2019
```

or

```
$origDate = Sat Jan 19 16:8:39 2019
```

This will fail because its looking for a leading 0. How can I fix this?

```
$oldDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('l M d H:i:s Y', $origDate);
$origDate = $oldDate->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: That's a pain. [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) doesn't seem to specify any formatting characters which allow for a lack of leading zeros for minutes or seconds (although it does for dates, and hours). I think you could probably use a regular expression or other string function to look for these anomalies and pad the strings with appropriate zeros before you feed them to createFromFormat. They probably wouldn't be too hard to locate because of the `:`s and/or space nearby.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is overly simplistic, but PHP is already able to parse that format automatically without using `createFromFormat()`, so you should be able to just use:

```
$oldDate = new DateTime($origDate);
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c45f841e566de92e0d17a9c28e55278154edb66e

Comment: That's odd. I tested it here. https://3v4l.org/GSVMB  and it seemed to work just fine. wonder why it would be different?

Comment: @soldfor you just need to use the format method. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d18dcedadf883c07f3f5bbeb79d4a4136704709

Answer (score 2):

You can do that:

```
$origDate = 'Sat Jan 19 16:8:39 2019';

$origDate = preg_replace('~:\K\d\b|\b\d(?=:)~', '0$0', $origDate);

echo $origDate;
```

`\b` looks for a word boundary (limit between a digit (or a letter or an underscore) and another character.
`\K` changes the position of the match result.
`(?=..)` is a lookahead assertion that checks forward if the subpattern match. The content matched in the subpattern isn't included in the match result.

Note: I jumped too quickly on my old horse, @Don'tPanic​'s answer is obviously the way to go.

Comment: This is great, but not sure it accounts for the `16:15:3` example as well?

Comment: @ADyson: did you test it?

Comment: This is great, but yeah, it doesn't take into account the seconds being an issue. At any given time, a date may have a minute or a second or both with no leading 0.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes I did: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc2074ea918e4a02afe36ef4a9f306a255a17b26 . I was just being polite and giving you the chance to consider it before posting an actual test result :-)

Comment: Great... just ran it and came into this also being an issue. Mon Jan 21 0:8:9 2019 I didnt think about searches after 12:08:09 AM

Comment: @soldfor Hours shouldn't be an issue, if that's what you're referring to in your last comment. createFromFormat can tolerate that. The manual says "G and H - 24-hour format of an hour with or without leading zeros 0 through 23 or 00 through 23"

Comment: @Andreas doesn't matter about the date. createFromFormat can tolerate leading zeros in dates and hours, just not in minutes and seconds.

Comment: What is weird, first off, thank you! but, Tues Jan 22 14:2:39 2019 does not work... but Sat Jan 19 17:8:32 2019 does. why would that be?

Comment: Didn't know that!

Comment: @soldfor `Tues Jan 22 14:2:39 2019` works with my code.

Comment: @Andreas it actually didnt. the reason why is because with PHP, it looks for the day to be Tue, not Tues. so I created a function to split up the date and properly rename it to Tue is the day was Tues.

Comment: @soldfor if you use the wrong format in the tue/tues then that is obviously not a issue of the regex function. You asked for adding the leading zeros. But that can also be corrected with regex

Comment: this code worked with Tues also, when you start making a new string from it, it didnt. or either code. I haven't accepted an answer because both of you guys are right.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly simpler regex.
Just looking for a single digit without a neighbor.

```
$origDate = 'Sat Jan 1 6:8:3 2019';

$origDate = preg_replace("/\b\d{1}\b/", '0$0', $origDate);

echo $origDate; //Sat Jan 01 06:08:03 2019
```